# UIAlertView dismisses itself

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I have a UIAlertView that is called like so

```
let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Load Discovered!", message: "Please click confirm to confirm the collection of load: "+code, preferredStyle: .alert)
ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
present(ac, animated: true)
```

This presents itself over a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`

My issue is, it dismisses itself almost instantly when it appears, it doesn't wait for the OK input.

I figure it's something to do with the fact it's displaying on top of an `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` I'm just not sure what to do about it

Comment: @kcpac in Swift 3 it's now `present(UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?)`.

Comment: it presents itself, are you sure? Which view is actually doing the presenting?  In other words If you were to write it as `self.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)` then which class would `self` be referring to?

Comment: Post your full code with presentation logic of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer